# How to check if a style has been applied in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to check if a particular style has been applied to an element. Preferably using the css selector.

EG:

```xml
...
<div id="my_div" style="display: block; background-color:#fff;">
    some content
</div>
...
```

How do I test that display is block regardless of the background color?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Worked it out:

```
command: assertAttribute or verifyAttribute
Target : css=#my_div@style
value : *display: block*
```

The asterisk is a wild card.