# Selenium IDE - How to check whether element has some [style] attribute or not in testcase?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

So, my test has the following command-target-value:

```
store attribute
id=loadGameButton
*visible*
```

> Trying to find id=loadGameButton... Failed:16:58:58
>
> Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms

I tried this [How to check if a style has been applied in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806747/how-to-check-if-a-style-has-been-applied-in-)
And this [Selenium IDE cannot find ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960290/selenium-ide-cannot-find-id)

```
store attribute
css=#loadGameButton@style
*inline*
```

```
store attribute
css=[id='loadGameButton']
*inline*
```

but doesn't work either: it always returns OK without correspondence to what I am trying to check.

https://github.com/Areso/1255-burgomaster/tree/master/selenium-ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[store attribute](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#store-attribute) doesn't check value of attribute, it just save the value of selected element. To check it, you should use `assert` or `verify` commands.

```
store attribute | css=<path_to_element>@style | tmp
assert | tmp | <expected_style_value>
```

*path_to_element* - css selector of element

For example, you can use 'width:100%' to replace *expected_style_value*

Comment: Wow, it seems now I got the idea. Could you describe, how could I check partial match?
`assert on tmp with value top: 310px` Failed:16:23:09`
`Actual value 'top: 310px; left: 20px; visibility: visible;' did not match 'top: 310px'`. I tried to add asterisk (star) before and after the value, doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think it is not possible to check with just one assert command. Firstly you should use `execute script` in which you save result of comparison *tmp* and *top: 310px* in new variable(or you can use the same variable) and then use `assert | tmp | true` which will check result of comparison.

Comment: `executeScript on n = tmp.indexOf("310px");` Failed: 19:55:18 tmp is not defined

Comment: Here I use regexp to find style and save result in tmp variable `executeScript | return /310px/.test(${tmp})| tmp`